# app-only policy in SharePoint Hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, authorization

Is it possible to use app-only policy in a SharePoint-Hosted App? All examples on Internet are using Provider-Hosted App which uses Managed code. I would like implement it in a SharePoint-hosted app using JavaScript. Appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use app-only policy in SharePoint hosted app. For a SP hosted app it is always app+user context. Refer [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179892(v=office.15).aspx#Approve). The NOTE in the documentation reads

> Apps that do not make OAuth authenticated calls (for example, apps that are only JavaScript running in the app web) cannot use the app-only policy